# Change Default SMS App handler Android Q RoleManger

Tags: android, android-studio

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        RoleManager roleManager = context.getSystemService(RoleManager.class);
        // check if the app is having permission to be as default SMS app
        boolean isRoleAvailable = roleManager.isRoleAvailable(RoleManager.ROLE_SMS);
        if (isRoleAvailable){
            // check whether your app is already holding the default SMS app role.
            boolean isRoleHeld = roleManager.isRoleHeld(RoleManager.ROLE_SMS);
            if (isRoleHeld){
                Intent roleRequestIntent = roleManager.createRequestRoleIntent(RoleManager.ROLE_SMS);
                ((AppCompatActivity)context).startActivityForResult(roleRequestIntent, ConstantsValues.REQUEST_CODES.REQUEST_RESET_SMS_HANDLER);
            }
        }
    }else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
        intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, Custom_SharedPreference.getInstance(context).getDefaultSMSPackage());
        ((AppCompatActivity)context).startActivityForResult(intent, ConstantsValues.REQUEST_CODES.REQUEST_RESET_SMS_HANDLER);
    }
```

This is working fine when Change SMS App to MyApp default handler but When I change MyApp to again Default SMS App then its not working and activityResult return 0 Activity.Cancle.
This is happend only Android Q other Versions working fine.

Comment: What permission you had added?

Comment: if (isRoleHeld) or if (!isRoleHeld)?

Comment: What permission you had added?
>> This is for change default SMS handler permission

Comment: if (isRoleHeld) or if (!isRoleHeld)?
>> First time when assign handler then its working fine with (isRoleHeld) but after complete work I want to assign previous Handler which was default handler for SMS then its not working

Comment: Got the same issue, anyone have found a solution to this problem? Got users complaining they are no longer asked to restore old default SMS app!

Answer (score 1):

In short, it's not possible to revert default SMS app.

As a work-around I decided to open the previous default SMS app using this code:

```
runIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(newDefaultSmsApp);
```

Having the same issue, I tried various workaround, like using old method to request a change of default SMS app, however the OS doesn't care at all. Using RoleManager, when requesting to "revert" the role back to default/previous SMS app, the logs shows something like this:

```
2021-06-18 08:23:06.246 1770-5101/? I/ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.provider.Telephony.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT cmp=com.google.android.permissioncontroller/com.android.permissioncontroller.role.ui.RequestRoleActivity (has extras)} from uid 10043
2021-06-18 08:23:06.246 1770-5101/? W/PermissionPolicyService: Action Removed: starting Intent { act=android.provider.Telephony.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT cmp=com.google.android.permissioncontroller/com.android.permissioncontroller.role.ui.RequestRoleActivity (has extras) } from ccc71.sb (uid=10043)
```

Note the Action Removed on second line.

So in summary, it's only possible to request the role for self, but impossible to revert. A real bummer for backup apps that Google is making look bad, like so many other apps these days.

Comment: That's what I do in my app as well, however it got rejected by Google because:

Your app does not satisfy the requirements for default handler capability. 
• Your app doesn’t automatically revert the default handler or prompt the user to revert the default handler after performing the SMS restore operation. Please update your app to make sure that it automatically reverts or prompts the user to revert the default handler.